# How do I write this line of code without using enumerate for (i, n) in enumerate(names)

Tags: python

how do I write this line of code without using enumerate

for (i, n) in enumerate(names):

Comment: You can use a counter variable.

Comment: `enumerate` effectively does the same as: `for i, n in zip(range(len(names)), names): ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerate() method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of enumerate object. So it is basicly an auto indexed loop.

Code Sample

```
names = ["adam", "eve", "genette"]

# enumerate
for (i, n) in enumerate(names):
    print(i, n)

# same without enumerate
i = 0
for n in names:
    print(i,n)
    i+=1
```